# Split Window Location URL and JOIN with data attribute value and refresh the page

Tags: javascript

Want to get value from data-key and join with .html. Done below logic, but its not appending in windows url.

Initial Url will be - http://www.test.com/en/location/london.html

Based on key value (Ex:258888) collected need to append inside url like http://www.test.com/en/location/london.258888.html

Thanks

```js
$('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(){
  let getDataKey = $(this).attr('data-key');
  let getWindowLocation = location.pathname.split('/')[1];
  let getLocationVal = getWindowLocation.split('.');
  getLocationVal.join(getDataKey);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
  $('a.dropdown-item').on('click', function(){
    let getDataKey = $(this).attr('data-key');
    let getWindowLocation = window.location.href;
    let getLocationVal = getWindowLocation.replace(/\.html/, "." + getDataKey + ".html");
    console.log(getLocationVal);
    window.location.replace(getLocationVal); //To redirect to the new url

  });
```